# How can I get an object from an array based on the object printed into a textarea from another array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, textarea

I'm trying to make a simple game for a museum website that tells you what city you may have lived in, and what hotel you may have owned based on a dataset of 1900s hotels. I want to have the city button call a random city which prints into a textarea, and then based on the value of that textarea have the hotel button call a random hotel from the array of hotels that were in that city. See my attempt below, thanks!

```
<script> var City = Array(
 "Nambour","Adavale",) 

function randomCity() {
 var randomCity = City[Math.floor(Math.random() * City.length)];
 document.getElementById('randomCity').value = randomCity;
}

var NambourHotel = Array(
 "Millchester",
 "Carrington ",
 "Royal",
 "Ellendean",
)

function randomNambourHotel() {
  var randomNambourHotel = NambourHotel[Math.floor(Math.random() *NambourHotel.length)];
 document.getElementById('randomNambourHotel').value = randomNambourHotel;
}

document.getElementByClass('hotel_button').onkeyup = function() {

  var text_value = document.getElementById('randomCity').value;

  if (text_value.includes("Nambour") === true) {
  randomNambourHotel();
  } else {}
}

</script>

   <button class="city_button" type="randomCity"   onclick="randomCity();">WHAT REGION MIGHT YOU HAVE LIVED IN?        
   </button>

  <div class="city_output">
     <div id="city_wrap">
       <textarea name="randomCity" id="randomCity" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
     </div>
  </div>


  <button class="hotel_button" type="randomNambourHotel">WHAT HOTEL MIGHT YOU HAVE OWNED?</button>

  <div class="hotel_output">
     <div id="hotels_wrap">
      <textarea name="randomNambourHotel" id="randomNambourHotel" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
     </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arkatark/L9yxzbd1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this solution.
I have added hotels array for each cities, And while clicking on hotels buttons, a random hotel from the hotels in the selected city will be populated.

```
var City = Array(
  "Nambour",
  "Adavale",
)

function randomCity() {
  var randomCity = City[Math.floor(Math.random() * City.length)];
  document.getElementById('randomCity').value = randomCity;
  document.getElementById('randomNambourHotel').value = "";
}

var NambourHotel = {'Nambour' : [
  "Millchester",
  "Carrington ",
  "Royal",
  "Ellendean",
],
'Adavale': [
  "Millchester-a",
  "Carrington-a",
  "Royal-a",
  "Ellendean-a",
]
}

function randomNambourHotel() {
  var city = document.getElementById('randomCity').value;
  var hotelsInselectedCity = NambourHotel[city]
  var randomNambourHotel = hotelsInselectedCity[Math.floor(Math.random() * hotelsInselectedCity.length)];
  document.getElementById('randomNambourHotel').value = randomNambourHotel;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/31xzd680/